# Javascript Typewriter Looping Infintely

Tags: javascript

I am using a typewriter effect from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/hi-im-si/embed/DHoup?height=265&theme-id=0&slug-hash=DHoup&default-tab=js%2Cresult&user=hi-im-si&embed-version=2).

```
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
          new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

Problem is, I am very new to JavaScript. Currently, the typing loops infinitely. I would like it to just play once through and then stop (leaving the last set of text on the page). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Quick'n'dirty:

Replace

```
if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
}
```

By

```
if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is so close to what I'm looking for! But when I implement, now the typewriter stops after the first set of words, and never types the second set etc. In the codepen, it types "Hi, I'm Si." but never types the rest (i.e. "I am Creative.", "I Love Design.", "I Love to Develop."). I'm looking for it to type each of the sentences, but stop typing after the last one ("I love to Develop"). Thanks for the help so far!